# What is (t *SimpleAsset) in this function

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric

```
func (t *SimpleAsset) Init(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) peer.Response
```

I have been trying to understand `hyperledger` in which we use `Go` language for `Chaincode`. But here I am unable to understand what the `(t* SimpleAsset)` is.
I do understand that unit is the name of the function, stub part is the argument and `peer.Response` is the return type. As I am new to `Go` please help me thank you.

Comment: `(t* SimpleAsset)` says that this is a method for `SimpleAsset` struct

Comment: Does that mean in go structs have methods like classes or something else?

Comment: This should clear everything :-). https://gobyexample.com/methods

Comment: @Malice  thank you it was very helpful

Comment: Sorry for overstepping, but I don't think this deserves a -1 as it can be confusing to understand that Go chaincode is really just pure Go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following code:

```
func (t *SimpleAsset) Init(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) peer.Response
```

`(t *SimpleAsset)` is the *receiver*. Go, unlike many other languages allows you to add methods to *any* (user defined) type (including functions!), and the type you are adding the method to is refered to here.

Notice that the author of this code names his receiver `t` instead of something like `self` or `this`? In Go there is no special rule for naming a receiver, you just name it like you would a parameter.

[Go by example](https://gobyexample.com/methods) has a nice clear explanation of the basics, but [the Go specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) is also very helpful.